# UITabBarController Change Color of "More" Tab

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I'm having UITabBarController's with more than 5 tabs. Now i'm confused how to change the title color of "More" which is black as default to white. Also how to hide the tableview lines of the cells. Like in tableview we add UIView into tableview's footer. How to do it in this scenario ?

[image]

Comment: you want to hide all lines or only the extra lines?

Comment: Only the extra lines.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks :) It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the lines select the table and set the `Separator` to `none` in IBInspector.

To change the title color use following code in appdelegate:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(),
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 18)!
]
```

To remove the extra lines/separator, just drag and drop an UIView below the Prototype cell, it will act as a Table footer, set its height to 1.